# Does a python program that has been compiled into an executable run faster than running the python program in an interpreter?

Tags: python, optimization, interpreter, py2exe

I've tried looking for this question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a pretty computationally intense python program with multiple modules and classes that are used for computer vision applications.

My question is: "If I convert the python script(s) to an executable using something like py2exe, will the program run faster and more efficiently than running the original .py files in an interpreter?". Thanks for your time and comments in advance.

Comment: no .... it still runs in a compiler ... now you can write it in a compiled python interpreter and then compile it and you *may* see some gain

Answer (score 2):

No, it's just a convenience, it has no real bearing on execution speed. Things like Py2exe just bundle a Python interpreter together with your source code into a single package, so it's easier for a user to manage.

To speed up execution you can either try using PyPy, a JIT compiler, or try writing the bottlenecks of your program in C. Also see if you can't leverage already existing libraries built for speed, such as NumPy.